# Defining Polymer computed property based on an array mutation event and another property

Tags: javascript, polymer

I'm trying to define a computed polymer property which depends on an array mutation event and another custom property. For some reason the compute function isn't being called by polymer but when I drop one of the two dependencies, everything works like a charm.

```
item: {
    type: Object,
    value: {
        votes: []
    }
},
authId: {
    type: String,
    value: '123'
},
voted: {
    type: Boolean,
    notify: true,
    computed: 'computeVoted(item.votes.*, authId)'
}
```

**EDIT:** Updated the example due to some misunderstanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works fine for me. Do you spot the difference in the snippet below?

```js
Polymer({
  is: 'my-elem',
  
  properties: {
    prop: {
      type: String,
      value: 'prop'
    },
    array: {
      type: Object,
      value: {
        items: []
      }
    },
    computed: {
      computed: 'compute(array.items.*, prop)'
    }
  },
  
  mutateArr: function() {
    this.push('array.items', 'arr');
  },
  
  compute: function(arr, prop) {
    return prop + ';' + arr.base.length;
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import"/>
</head>

<body>
  <my-elem></my-elem>
  
  <dom-module id="my-elem">
    <template>
      <input type="button" value="Mutate array" on-tap="mutateArr" />
      <input type="text" value="{{prop::input}}" />
      <br/>
      <span>{{computed}}</span>
    </template>
  </dom-module>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it isn't exactly the same, I'm listening to `array.items.*` (in your example)

Comment: You're right. I fixed the snippet and still works :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a running example of what you are trying to achieve. It's always recommended to initialize the values on which `observers` or `comptuted` are set.

```html
<base href="http://polygit.org/components/">
<script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="button-group">
  <template>
    <style></style>
    <div on-tap='changeAuthId'>Change AuthId</div>
    <div on-tap='changeItem'>Change item</div>
    {{voted}}
  </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'button-group',
    properties: {
      item: {
        type: Object,
        value: function() {
          return {
            votes: [{
              one: 'one'
            }, {
              two: 'two'
            }]
          }
        }
      },
      authId: {
        type: String,
        value: 'test'
      },
      voted: {
        type: String,
        notify: true,
        computed: 'computeVoted(item.votes.*,authId)'
      }
    },
    computeVoted: function(firstVal, authId) {
      //firstVal will be an Object containing three variables 
      //base: which will have item.voted object
      //path: which will contain path of changed value/s
      //value: which will contain new value/s
      return 'Path for changed value: ' + firstVal.path + ' AuthId: ' + authId
    },
    changeAuthId: function() {
      this.authId = "new id"
    },
    changeItem: function() {
      var three = {
        three: 'three'
      };
      this.set('item.votes.0', three);
    }
  });
</script>


<button-group></button-group>
```

Comment: the `votes` property inside `item` should be an array

Comment: It will work even if you have an array of string rather than object as shown in snippet above